# I can not use freemarker when i am building my spring boot's web project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, freemarker

**My request can get into my method of my Welcomecontroller,but it semms that this method can not return a freemarker page to me or spring boot didn't distinguish freemarker(I have put .ftl files into /resources/templates/)**

When I input the url http://localhost:8080/index

*I got this from my chrome and don't report any errors in my IDEA's console:*

Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sat Jan 04 22:52:53 CST 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

*My code is as follow:*

```
@Controller
public class WelcomeController {

    @Value("${application.message}")
    private String message;

    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String welcome(Map<String, Object> model) {
        model.put("time", new Date());
        model.put("message", this.message);
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class QuestionsiteApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(QuestionsiteApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

*welcome.ftl:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    Date: ${time?date}
    <br>
    Time: ${time?time}
    <br>
    Message: ${message}
</body>
</html>
```

*application.properties:*

```
application.message: Hello, Andy
```

*pom.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>cn.UU</groupId>
    <artifactId>questionsite</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>questionsite</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <commons-lang3-version>3.1</commons-lang3-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: this is a standard sample i got from official example.why can‘t i run normally？

Comment: I think you are missing `@RequestMapping("/welcome")` in the Controller class `WelcomeController`

Comment: my url‘s request can enter the method of welcome, but it can not return a freemarker's view.

Comment: Your templates should have the prefix `ftlh` not `ftl`. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2-Release-Notes#freemarker-templates-configuration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Spring Boot 2.2 the suffix for Freemarker templates is `ftlh` not `ftl`.

This is documented in the [Release Notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2-Release-Notes#freemarker-templates-configuration).

Rename your `welcome.ftl` to `welcome.ftlh` and it will work with the default configuration.

Comment: Wonderful!!!!!!Thank for your advice. Before your advice,I sovled the problem through my own way.According to the spring boot references document, intelliJ IDEA  may reorders my classpath.So i add "spring.freemarker.template-loader-path=classpath:/templates/" and "spring.freemarker.suffix=.ftl" to my application.properties according to its suggestion.In a words, there are two effective methods~

Comment: Your solution doesn't really solve it, it only restores the old settings for the `suffix` which is what makes it work.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to application.yml

```
server:
  servlet:
    context-path: /cx
```

and then try http://localhost:8080/cx/index

Make sure you put `.ftl` files into `/resources/templates/`

P.S. 
You don't need this dependency, as it is already included in `spring-boot-starter-web`:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you!       But, it didn't work~ My request can get into my method of my Welcomecontroller,but it semms that this method can not return a freemarker page to me.    In the other words, your advice has the same effect as before.

Comment: Most probably freemarker view resolver is not configured correctly. Can you share your project?

Comment: I have shown all my content. my project almost like the official sample.As far as i am   concerned，because of auto-configuration, Freemarker does not seem to need any configurations.

Comment: Please provide link to the sample you are referring to.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/2.1.x/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-freemarker

Comment: Ok, I solvoed the problem. I got a message from spring boot reference documentation which say that intelllij IDEA may reorders my classpath differently. So i must configure my freemarker load path.

Answer (score 0):

For springboot 2.6.0

**Controller**

`WelcomeController.java`

```java
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

...


@Controller
public class WelcomeController {

    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String welcome(Model model) {

        Map<String, Object> mydataMap = new HashMap<>();

        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd LLLL yyyy");
        String formattedDateString = localDate.format(formatter);

        mydataMap.put("Message", "hello");
        mydataMap.put("Date", formattedDateString);

        model.addAttribute("mydata", mydataMap); // the attrbuteName should same with the corresponding variable in the template file

        return "welcome"; // same with the template file name
    }
}
```

`welcome.ftl`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <#list mydata as mykey, myvalue>
         <br> ${mykey}: ${myvalue}
    </#list>
</body>
</html>
```

`application.properties`

```
# 
# Default value true for springboot 2.6.0
spring.freemarker.enabled=true
# Default value /templates
spring.freemarker.template-loader-path=classpath:/templates
# Default value ftlh
spring.freemarker.suffix=.ftl
```

`pom.xml`

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```